# How to specifically use Roboto Thin and Normal font

Tags: html, css

i am trying to use Google font (Roboto) on my website. i attached the link to my html files

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

and i also attached this to my CSS

```
h1,h2
{
  font-family: 'Roboto: 300', Century Gothic;
}
h3,h4,h5,h6{
  font-family: 'Roboto: 400', Century Gothic;
}
```

but when i load it via my andriod phone and PC, it still doesn't change. Please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The font name you're using is not correct. It is just 'Roboto'. You want to do:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Century Gothic;
}
```

If you want to use different font weights, you could then do something like:

```
h1, h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it works perfectly,  and I understand it better now.

Comment: Glad I could help!  You can accept my answer if it solved your problem.  Thanks!